# Output 1 Row only of PHP Array as Hyperlink

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, hyperlink

I’m outputting the result of a MySQL query that contains information about users and chosen subjects.  One of the rows contains an email address. I would like php to output this row only as a hyperlink, but leave the rest as text. How do I do this?

```
$resultSet = $db->query ("...my query");  
echo $resultSet -> num_rows;
While($rows = $resultSet ->fetch_assoc())
{
   $subject [1] = $rows['First_Name'];
   $subject [2] = $rows['Surname'];
   $subject [3] = $rows['Email_Address'];
   $subject [4] = $rows['Subject1'];
   $subject [5] = $rows['Subject2'];
   $subject [6] = $rows['Subject2'];

  $subjectOutput = array_filter($subject, 'strlen'); 

  $subjectString = implode($subjectOutput, '<br/>'); 

  $output .= "<p> ". $subjectString."  </p>";
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check `Email_Address` for emptiness and if it is not empty - wrap it in `<a>` tag:

```
$subject [3] = $rows['Email_Address'] 
    ? ('<a href="#">' . $rows['Email_Address'] . '</a>') 
    : '';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$resultSet = $db->query ("...my query");  
echo $resultSet -> num_rows;
While($rows = $resultSet ->fetch_assoc())
{
   $subject [1] = $rows['First_Name'];
   $subject [2] = $rows['Surname'];
   $subject [3] = "<a href='mailto:" . $rows['Email_Address'] . ">" . $rows['Email_Address'] . "</a>";
   $subject [4] = $rows['Subject1'];
   $subject [5] = $rows['Subject2'];
   $subject [6] = $rows['Subject2'];

  $subjectOutput = array_filter($subject, 'strlen'); 

  $subjectString = implode($subjectOutput, '<br/>'); 

  $output .= "<p> ". $subjectString."  </p>";
}
```